# Customizing the xmlns:a= tag in a soapresponse from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, namespaces

I'm creating a service to respond to calls.
However the client(not written by me) cannot read the response.
What we have located is that this seems to be due to th missmatching namespace in the

```
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Classes"
```

Is there anyway to override this namespace?
I'm rather sure it is.

The [ServiceBehavior] tag has the "http://correctnamespace.com" NameSpace

The BindingNameSpace in the app.config has the  "http://correctnamespace.com" Namespace

The [ServiceContract] has the  "http://correctnamespace.com" Namespace

I've looked at the OperationsContract to see if I can locate it but without luck.

the namespace needs to be "http://correctnamespace.com"

Below is a full example of the Upper part of the SOAPresponse

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<getAddressResponse xmlns="http://correctnamespace.com">
<getAddressReturn xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Classes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:PropertyChanged i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ComponentModel"/>
<a:addressField>Happystreet 21</a:addressField>
```

I hope someone can help me sort this ut ASAP.

Added information

The service is created to fit he client.

The client is predesigned and the service is created based on a WSDL file provided from the client creator.

Also  note that the client cannot be modified. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by copying all the classed from the WSDL and made DataContracts of them instead, in this it's possible to define the NameSpace just like for the ServiceContract.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://correctnamespace.com")]
public class Amount
{
```

Thanks for evryone who took timeto help me solve his.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions.

First, assuming that the server side code sand stubs are all correct and functioning properly, ask the client to regen the client side stubs. It is possible that somehow the stub they are using is old or has been modified.

Second, if the serverside is also not working properly I recommend recreating your WSDL from scratch. Proper SOAP coding is WSDL to code creation. So if your WSDL was generated by a tool it will have a certain naming convention and while you can manually change things like your xmlns, if you miss one (which is what it sounds like happened) it will mess up your code. So go back and make the WSDL from scratch and generate the code classes from the WSDL that way you can name everything the way you want it to be named.

Comment: Added aditinal Infoto the post. This explains more and to why I cannot use the solution provided by you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the added information, I again have two suggestions.

First, is that you will have to go in and manually change the soap response AddressReturn namespace and follow the chain so that any references to the aforementioned response has the correct namespace. It will be tedious and annoying, but you could program an xml parser that can find any references to such field and make the necessary changes in both the schema and the WSDL.

Second is to use the WSDL provided to you by the client in order to create your own WSDL that will work with the client but has the naming conventions that you want incorporated. WSDL first coding can be done this way and is sometimes recommended because it provides the skeleton that you follow in creating and modifying to make it your own and fit your needs.

Comment: That does indeed seem very tedious,isn't there any override method in somewhere in the contract like [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://correctnamespace.com", Name = "MyService")]? this is how I set the general namespace for the Interface

Comment: Solved by copying all the lassed from the WSDL and made DataContracts o them instead, in this is't possible to define the NameSpace just like for the ServiceContract